# Flexbox grid item which uses full width before growing in height

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm looking for flexbox in a grid cell which:

- flows in the column direction
- uses a minimum height before wrapping
- grows in height if all width is filled while wrapping

It's a bit hard to explain in words, hopefully an example should make things clearer. In the example below, I'd like `content`, to always be a minimum of 100px tall. However, `content` should not be taller than this unless it has first filled all of the horizontal space in the grid cell.

Is this possible to do somehow?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 200px;
  grid-template-rows: auto min-content;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "content sidebar";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.content-block {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <header>title</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div style="height: 50px" class="content-block"></div>
    <div style="height: 75px" class="content-block"></div>
    <div style="height: 110px" class="content-block"></div>
    <div style="height: 80px" class="content-block"></div>
    <div style="height: 40px" class="content-block"></div>
    <div style="height: 40px" class="content-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: min height won't do the job, the container will grow over the min-height and wrapping to another column will never happen. If you set a max-height or an height, you might have an horizontal scrollbar if the grid doesn't grow.

Comment: in you want to fill the width, then why the column direction? keep it row and you will have what you want, no?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Good question, for two reasons: first, the content that comes in is meant to be displayed in columns, starting at the left and moving right. Second, if the direction was `row`, there'd be awkward gaps between rows

Comment: as I expected, you are looking for mansory layout ... then this is what you need : https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/8620333

Comment: Mmm yes, you're exactly right @TemaniAfif, just tried it and it works great. If you want to post an answer to that extent, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I will close as duplicate then, I don't think I can add more than what is already there